# Number of Lattice Points inside a Parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Consider a sub-lattice of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ generated by two points $a$ and $b$. Given a parallelogram with vertices in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, is a formula known for how many points of the sub-lattice $\langle a,b\rangle$ lie on or inside it?

Comment: What you mean by integer vectors?

Comment: You can try [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem)

Comment: @mrprottolo I mean vectors with integer coordinates. I have restated the question, and I'm not sure how to apply Pick's Theorem or if it is applicable.